# How to search for questions that I might be able to answer?

Tags: discussion, search, tag-search

I know a little bit about ASP.Net and C#, so I go to stackoverflow.com and click on each tag I created.

I see some people answer in a lot of topics - CSS, Java, C# and so on.

I'm wondering how they find those questions. Do I have to create all tags (like I did previously), and click on each tag manually?

Could you please share some better technique to filter questions (that you might be able to answer), so that I can contribute more to the community?

[image]

Comment: I like to try to answer all sorts of questions as long as I think I can provide a useful answer. I just click "Questions" and then go from there. It is interesting to see the large swath of technology being used, even if I cannot address all of the issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a tag search. You can do and/or as such:

### Both: `[asp.net][c#]`

[image]

### Or: `[asp.net] or [c#]`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One search that I am fond of is (and this only works if you have favorite tags) is to search inside of questions tagged with favorite tags which are not closed and have no answers.

[My tags, no answers, not closed, sorted by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano)

(note: My tags is your tags - it uses a flag that will grab the tags **you** have favorited using `intags:mine`)

Answer (score 4):

You can combine all the tags you like and open them in a single browser tab. Put

```
[asp.net] OR [C#]
```

in the search box to  watch these 2 tags. If you click on *newest* then you will get new questions instantly after they have been asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an RSS aggregator te get notified whenever a question gets posted in a tag you are interested in. There's a link at the bottom of each page to make it easier for you.

[image]